# Graphql Prisma with nodejs query question

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I want to write SQL query to

```
SELECT 
   sm.menu_name
FROM
   shop.menu as sm LEFT JOIN shop.shop_menu as ssm
ON
   sm.idmenu = ssm.menu_id
WHERE
   sm.menu_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
Group by 
   sm.menu_name
Order by rand()
```

How can I write this with below?

```
await prisma.menu.findMany({})
```

Please help!

Comment: We have no knowledge of your datamodel or schema. We need both of these items to even begin looking in to helping.

Answer (score 0):

- Your LEFT JOIN is not needed
- LIKE CONCAT -> StringFilter for prisma has contains, startsWith and endsWith
- ORDER BY rand() is not supported by prisma, you have some options: shuffle the array in code or use prisma.raw for your query.

Documentation:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/filtering
https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/raw-database-access

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like:

```
prisma.menu.groupBy({
    by: ['menu_name'],
    having: {
        shop_menu  : {
            menu_name: { contains: yourVariableName }
        }
    }
 })
```

But as @mazzaker said, you will have to order by rand by yourself :/